# Django Serializing of ValueQuerySet

Tags: json, django, serialization

So I got the following ValueQuerySet

```
records = Maintenance.objects.values('failure').annotate(fcount=Count('failure'))
Out[13]: <QuerySet [{'failure': 'Bend Pin', 'fcount': 2}, {'failure': 'Winding Failure', 'fcount': 2}, {'failure': 'Degraded Capacitor', 'fcount': 2}]>
```

I tried serializing this with Django's serializer;

```
from django.core import serializers
serializers.serialize('json', records, fields('failure', 'fcount'))
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I know I can serialize the records with json.dumps, but I want to understand why Django's serializer gives me this error.
I'm running on Python 3.8.2. and Django 3.0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/#serializing-django-objects)

> Actually, the second argument can be any iterator that yields ***Django model instances*** , but it’ll almost always be a `QuerySet`.

In your case, The **`records`** is an *iterable*, but, the ***contents of the `records` is not a Django model instance, but a `dict` object***

```
In [13]: type(records)                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[13]: django.db.models.query.QuerySet

In [14]: type(records[0])                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[14]: dict
```