# how to convert Django object into json?

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-views

Hi I'm trying to convert a Django queryset object into JSON but every time I try do it with the python JSON module I get this error: "TypeError: Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable". Here is the Django object: `titles = Queries.objects.values('Topic').distinct().` and here is what it returns `<QuerySet [{'Topic': 'Phone or Web'}, {'Topic': 'Time or Money'}, {'Topic': 'Power or Wisdom'}, {'Topic': 'Luxure or Camp!'}]>.

Now even when I try to use the django serilizers to try to solve this problem I get this error: "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'." Can anyone help me solve this? Here is my code for both situation.

code of the django serializers situation:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Queries
import json
from django.core.serializers import json

from django.core import serializers

def data_json():
    titles = Queries.objects.values('Topic').distinct()
    titles_json = serializers.serialize('json', titles)
    with open('topic.json', 'w') as file:
        data = json.dumps(titles_json)
        print(data, file=file)
    print(titles)



def index(request, query_title):
    queries = Queries.objects.all()
    page = Queries.objects.filter(Topic=str(query_title))
    # print(page)
    data_json()
    return render(request, 'Querie/index.html', {'queries': page})
```

and here how my code looked like when I was using the regular json module so the data_json funtion was like this:

```
import json

def data_json():
titles = Queries.objects.values('Topic').distinct()
with open('topic.json', 'w') as file:
    data = json.dumps(titles)
    print(data, file=file)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Serializing of ValueQuerySet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63701144/django-serializing-of-valuequeryset)

Comment: No not really to be honest I'm not sure I understand what the answer shown was telling to do.

Comment: The answer conveys that you can't serialize a ***`ValueQuerySet `*** (same as in your case) which is an iterable contains ***`dict` objects***, using *Django serializer*

Comment: Oh ok then how can I convert it into JSON?

Comment: have you tried ***`data = json.dumps(list(titles))`***?

Comment: Oh wow it worked thanks that was so simple yet this took me a while to figure out?

Answer (score 1):

What ever for objects in your QuerySet are, still it is a QuerySet. My guess is: you don't want serialize your QuerySet, rather the content, the objects in it. That said: you need to unpack the QuerySet and apply your serialization on each object in it.

example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
allUsers = User.objects.all() # QuerySet: allUsers
# apply your operation on each object in QuerySet (users) like this:
serializedData = [ json.dumps({'usrname': user.username, 
                  'mail': user.email}) for user in allUsers]
```

Your serialized data set is now in serializedData. Problem is, you want do things like this:

```
serializedData = [ json.dumps(user) for user in allUsers ]
```

but there is no such thing like a free lunch regarding json.dumps() and your objects, in this example User objects. You have two options:

(1) coding the dict like example above {'usrname': user.username......}) or

(2) you need to define a "class ObjectClassNameEncoder(JSONEncoder):" in case of User object "class UserEncoder(JSONEncoder):", this it's more 'sophisticated'. Bottom line: your path you have to look for: **JSONEncoder**.